# XML DOM -- Reading two nodes on the same lime

Tags: xml, dom, xml-parsing

I am looping through an XML document using dom that has a tree like this :

```
<value>
      <value2 number="3"><value3 needed="item1"/></value2>
      <value2 number="2"><value3 needed="item2"/></value2>
      <value2 number="1"><value3 needed="item3"/></value2>
</value>
```

And I have

```
NodeList value = aboveNodes.getChildNodes();
for(int i = 0; i < value.getLength(); i++) {
   Node value2 = value.item(i);
}
```

I am trying to get access to value3, so I can get the needed attribute.
However, I am unsure how to do so.

If the XML document was formated so the values were on separate lines ie.

```
<value2 number="3">
   <value3 needed="item1"/>
</value2>
```

I know I could do it with getChildNodes, but how do I do it when they are on the same line?

In other words :
**How do I get access to the needed attribute?**

Comment: There's no `value33` in your sample data.

Comment: Also, have you tried `getChildNodes` in this case, too? The XML specification doesn't say an element must start on a new line to become a child.

Comment: @choroba I have and it doesn't work, I can move them manually to new lines in the XML file and then getChildNodes works, but not how it is currently

Comment: Is `item1` your expected output?

Comment: What language and parser do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still have no idea why this happened, but once I deleted and then redownloaded the XML document getChildNodes worked fine in this context.